# Linker error when building an application with meschach library

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, scons, meschach

When I try to build my application I get linker error `undefined reference to (..)`. All functions that were not found are imported from meschach library. In my opinion library is properly installed:

```
whereis libmeschach
libmeschach: /lib/libmeschach.so /usr/lib/libmeschach.so /lib64/libmeschach.so
```

My SCons file:

```
import os
import sys
import functools

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.curdir
doc_path = functools.partial(os.path.join, PROJECT_ROOT, 'doc')
src_path = functools.partial(os.path.join, PROJECT_ROOT, 'src')
out_path = functools.partial(os.path.join, PROJECT_ROOT, 'build')

cpp_flags = {
    'linux2' : '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fopenmp -O3',
    'win32'  : '/w /MD /openmp'
}

env = Environment(ENV=os.environ,CPPFLAGS=cpp_flags[sys.platform])    
env.VariantDir(variant_dir=out_path(),src_dir=src_path())

env.Program(target=out_path('cholesky'), source=Glob(out_path('*.cpp')), LIBS=['m'])
```

I use Arch Linux 64bit.

Edit: I replaced SCons with Makefile but error still remains:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -I./externals/include
LIB=./externals/lib/meschach.a -lm

all: cholesky

cholesky: cholesky.o equation.o testing.o profiler.o parallelCholeskyTest.o matrix.o
$(CC) cholesky.o equation.o testing.o profiler.o parallelCholeskyTest.o matrix.o -o 
    main $(LIB)

 cholesky.o:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) src/cholesky.cpp

 equation.o: matrix.o
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) src/equation.cpp

 matrix.o:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) src/matrix.cpp

 testing.o:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) src/testing.cpp

 profiler.o:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) src/profiler.cpp

 parallelCholeskyTest.o:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) src/parallelCholeskyTest.cpp
```

Comment: Try adding `libmeschach` to list of libraries i.e. try changing `LIBS=['m']` to `LIBS=['m', 'meschach']`. Please check [this link](http://www.scons.org/doc/0.97/HTML/scons-user/x628.html) for more info on linking

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't help.

Comment: Hmm do you see the library being linked or anything when actual compilation happens? Can you check the exact `gcc` compilation command for which you get this error?

Comment: I updated my post so you can check it ;)

Comment: Hmm are you able to compile simple code which uses this library? (Also you can definitely improve your `makefile` ... I know that is not the problem & you might be making use of them for first time :))

Comment: Thanks. You helped me. I wrote a simple C file and it compiled well but when I changed the extension to *.cpp I couldn't link my binaries with the library.

Comment: Glad to help! Good that you could solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I solved it. This library cannot be included as a C++ library and you have to wrap each `#include` with `extern "C" { }`. Here you can find more about this issue: [C-library not linking using gcc/g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068129/c-library-not-linking-using-gcc-g)