# Unable to link a static C library in an Obj-C project (Xcode 4.6.3)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker, static-libraries

I'm trying to build a basic FTP client using libftp. I've compiled and archived it as `libftp.a` and placed it in `/usr/local/lib`. All the necessary headers I've placed in `/usr/local/include/ftp`.

Under Build Settings, I've set "Header Search Paths" to `/usr/local/include`, and I've set "Library Search Paths" to `/usr/local/lib`. For "Other Linker Flags", I've added `-lftp`.

Here is the shell of my C++ class:

**Connector.h:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ftp/ftp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class Connector{
    private:
        FtpConnection *connection;
    public:
        Connector();
        ~Connector();

        bool connect(const char *hostname, const char *port);
    };
```

**Connector.cc:**

```
#include "Connector.h"

Connector::Connector(){
    }

Connector::~Connector(){
    }

bool Connector::connect(const char *hostname, const char *port){
    ftpGetAddresses(hostname, port);
    printf("Connected!\n");
    return true;
    }
```

Upon compiling, this is the error I get:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "ftpGetAddresses(char
>   const*, char const*)", referenced from:
>         Connector::connect(char const*, char const*) in Connector.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It's probably worth noting that this is part of a Cocoa project, so the `Connector` class is `#included` in my `AppDelegate`, which is of course an Obj-C class. All of my Obj-C source files have the `.mm` extension.

I am certain that the lib is in working order, as I have no issue compiling a program on the command line with `gcc ... -lftp`. It's only a problem with Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it appears I just talked myself through my own problem. As I was typing the last part of my question, I realized that the issue was linking a C library in a C++ source file. `gcc` would compile just fine on command line, but `g++` gave me the same error as Xcode. One google search later I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068129/c-library-not-linking-using-gcc-g), which solved my problem beautifully. Basically, if you want a C library to be compatible with C++, you need to add

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

at the top of the library header file, and add

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

at the bottom of the file. I'll leave the question here hoping it will help someone else in the future.